# Zero overhead subscript operator for a set of values

Tags: c++

Assume we have a function with the following signature (the signature may not be changed, since this function is part of a legacy API):

```
void Foo(const std::string& s, float v0, float v1, float v2)
{ ... }
```

How can one access the last three arguments by index using the subscript operator `[]` without actually copying the data into some sort of container?

Regularly when I come across this kind of issue I put the values in a container, like `const std::array<float,3> args{v0,v1,v2};` and access these values using `args[0]`, which unfortunately needs to copy the values.

Another idea would be to access the arguments using a parameter pack, which in turn involves the creation of a templated function which seems to be overkill for this task.

*I'm aware that the version using the `std::array<>` might be suitable since the compiler probably will optimize this kind of stuff, however, this question is kind of academically motivated.*

Comment: How about an array of pointers?

Comment: If by "academically motivated" you mean to consider the question in a general way or purely from a language point of view, then it conflicts with the nature of the question. Overhead and optimizations is largely the domain of individual implementations of the language.

Comment: Copying the addresses of 3 `float`s may consume the same performance like copying the 3 `float`s themselves (if not even more). I would go with a local array of the 3 `float`s (and forget about the effort for copying). Btw. with the local copies of `float`s, you may even earn cache-locality.

Comment: Uh... you are **passing** those `float` values, to a legacy API which "may not be changed". So... you cannot change that these are **not** in a different format than they are... so what is your question? You aren't the one being called...?!?

Comment: @DevSolar My guess is that OP is *implementing* the `Foo` function, but may not change the signature.

Comment: @Scheff That is assuming naively generated assembly. Maybe some implementations will be able to optimize with an array of pointers while it won't be able to optimize with an array of copies? Edit : Either way, the goal of the question is to find a way that has 0 runtime overhead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are right. Passing arguments by register may be another option I didn't consider... Although, address of the register won't work as well... ;-)

Comment: @RaymondChen: Same difference. If the API defines those `float` to be passed as separate values, and OP can't change that, what is this question about what they **cannot** be changed **to** about?

Comment: @Scheff But again, even if you take the address of the `float` and the compiler can determine that there is no aliasing happening for that argument, the final compiled result might never actually take the address. Same with copying the values in an array. If it can be determined that the copy is never modified, the copy might not actually ever need to take place. It could be treated as a `float&` to the argument. The point is that nobody can say what will happen because this question isn't considering any specific implementation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Can we agree that the question has a smell of micro-optimization and that the OP should have provided a good reason for why it could pay out?

Comment: @Scheff I agree this smells of micro-optimization and the effort probably doesn't matter in that the payoff won't have any actual benefit. But I think it is still interesting and what is really missing is specifying the platform this code will run on. This is required information for just about any question about optimization to be meaningful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Not in a way that guarantees zero overhead, or overhead similar to that of array subscripting.

You could, of course, do something like `float* vs[]{&v0, &v1, &v2};`, and then dereference the result of `vs[i]`. For that matter, you could make a utility class to act as a transparent reference (to try to get around arrays of references being illegal), though the result is inevitably limited.

The ultimate problem, though, is that nothing in the standard guarantees (or even suggests) that function arguments be stored in any particular memory ordering. On most platforms, at least one of those `float`s is going to be in a register, meaning that there's just no way to natively subscript it.

If a group of objects does not start out as an array, it's not possible to treat them as an array.

Comment: Furthermore, I tried `std::array<float, 3> floats = { v0, v1, v2 }; someFunction(floats[0], floats[2], floats[1]);`, on godbolt, and gcc, msvc, and clang all propagate the value through the array, and no actual array is created at runtime. So just create the array.

Comment: "you could make a utility class to act as a transparent reference (to try to get around arrays of references being illegal)" - that already exists. It's called [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's one option. But because it supports rebinding, you can't transparently assign with, say, `vs[i] = 1.0f`, and `vs[0]=vs[1]` is going to let you down. Every UDT which pretends to be some other type is crap; you just have to choose which kind of crap you prefer.

Comment: Well, almost as I thought. FYI, I put the [std::array version](https://godbolt.org/z/cr5Xwv) and [@NathanOliver's solution](https://godbolt.org/z/_zDBHb) into GodBolt, both produce the same assembly, even MSVC does not struggle to get this kind of stuff sorted out.

Answer (score 5):

> Another idea would be to access the arguments using a parameter pack, which in turn involves the creation of a templated function which seems to be overkill for this task.

Not necessarily. One thing you can do is use `std::tie` to build a `std::tuple` of references to the function parameters and then access that tuple via `std::get`.  That should optimize out, but let you refer to the parameters as if they are part of a single collection.  That would look like

```
void Foo(const std::string& s, float v0, float v1, float v2)
{
    auto args = std::tie(v0, v1, v2);
    std::cout << std::get<1>(args);
}
```

It's not using `operator []`, and requires your indices be compile time constants, but you can now pass them to something else as one object.

Comment: This answer has the advantage that `std::tie` makes the intention abundantly clear. And `std::tie` is designed for aliasing collections of objects so it's the solution I would have the most confidence in being optimized out correctly. But you can't use a runtime index, which may or may not be required by OP. But if compile time indexing is fine this seems like *the* idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good point about the indices needing to be compile time constants.  Added that to the answer to make it completely clear.

Comment: +1. I like this approach since (as @FrançoisAndrieux already mentioned) it is evident to the reader what is going on here. However, a run time addressable index would be preferable (sorry for not explicitly stating this in the question). Still a nice solution when you are dealing with compile time constants.

Answer (score -2):

#### Danger Wil Robinson!  Danger!

This is going to be horribly implementation dependent, and an all around bad idea!  This relies on undefined behavior.  Less awful with set hardware and tools, but less as in "we're only going to eat 5 babies, not a full dozen".

Those three floats are on the stack next to each other.  I don't know if there are any packing rules for the stack.  I don't know which order on the the stack they'll be ("v0 v1 v2" vs "v2 v1 v0").  Hell, some optimized build might even put them in a different order just to optimize some oddball case that doesn't actually come up in real life.  I dunno.  But I suspect something like this will work.

```
void Foo(const std::string& s, float v0, float v1, float v2)
{
  float* vp = &v2;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    printf("%f\n", vp[i]);
  }
}
void main(void)
{
  Foo("", 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
}
```

> 3.0000
>
> 2.0000
>
> 1.0000

So it is possible.  It's also ugly, vile, evil, and probably both fattening and carcinogenic.

On GodBolt.org, using gcc x86-64 9.3, the above code worked fine.  In VS2017 intel/64, I had to use `float* vp = &v0` and `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 2)`.  Different alignment, different order, and *different output* (`1, 2, 3`, not `3, 2 1`).

I'm pretty sure I just consigned my soul to the Nth circle of hell.

Comment: Also both GodBolt and my local VS were debug builds.  Optimized builds could easily break the shit out of this vile code I've shat out upon an unsuspecting world.

Comment: Not the down voter, but why on earth would you suggest undefined behavior for production code?  As you've shown, different platforms produce different results so you know you wont get the same results on all platforms.

Comment: Who said anything about production code?  The OP specifically said "academically motivated".  My guess is the teacher wanted their students to think about where those values live (the stack).

Comment: *(the signature may not be changed, since this function is part of a legacy API)* Sounds like this function is production code.

Comment: @MarkStorer Whether or not this is production code, unless somehow otherwise established, you need to assume that UB is not acceptable. Even if you are correct that this is a student asking, providing a solution that relies on UB is implicitly wrong no matter how much the answer apologies for itself.